# Remove the hover red line on one of the menu Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

We have a site here: http://americanbitcoinacademy.com/

When I hover my mouse on the logo on the right side it has the red line:

[image]

It is ok to have a hover red line on text but I want to dissappear on this logo.

Basically here's what I used on my hover line and the logo:

```
#main-nav .navbar-nav>li>a:hover .menu-description{
color: #a6a6a6;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:after, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:focus:after {
    background-color: #ea1e24;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
#main-nav .navbar-nav>li>a{
padding-top: 48px;
}


#nav-menu-item-3247{
margin-top: -57px;
}
```

I tried to put :hover on the nav-item but it did not work out. You can use your inspector tools to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is in your pseudo element `::after`,

so apply this style targeting the last li using `last-of-type`:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li:last-of-type > a::after, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li:last-of-type > a:focus::after {
  background: transparent;
}
```

[image: SS]

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your site it seems to be making that line when you hover over it like the other nav bar items, the simple solution will be to remove the class that makes the red line appear for the nav bar items

Comment: It is ok to have a hover red line on text but I want to dissappear on this logo.

Comment: I mean remove the class that does the red highlighting from the logo.
Example: let's say class"red_line" makes the red line,
so every other nav bar has this class, EXCEPT the Logo

Answer (score 0):

Could you use visibility:hidden and target it only to the logo so that the other nav bar items keep the red bar, but that one is not viewable? Should be able to do this with the nav item id number

Comment: It is ok to have a hover red line on text but I want to dissappear on this logo.

Comment: Right, and this should remove the red line only on the logo if you apply it using the id nav-menu-item-3247

Answer (score 0):

Use `.menu-item-type-post_type` instead of `li`:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav >.menu-item-type-post_type> a:after,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.menu-item-type-post_type>a:focus:after {
    background-color: #ea1e24;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Or:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li.menu-item-type-custom> a:after,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li.menu-item-type-custom>a:focus:after {
    background-color: transparent;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```